# why do arrows < break this regex?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
$str = "for(var i = 0; i < aLinks.length; i++) {"; 

preg_replace( "!\s+!", "", $str  );
```

output: `for(vari=0;i`

My desired output is

```
for(var i=0;iaLinks.length;i++){
```

if I remove the arrow like this `$str = "for(var i = 0; i (no arrow here) aLinks.length; i++) {";` 
then I get the desired output.

Why does the back arrow break the regex?

What I want the regex to do is remove all tabs line breaks and spaces and nothing else. the strings may have operators like < or > etc and I want these to be ignored.

Comment: my first guess is to add slashes? ie \< or \> ??? its a bit annoying though to have to do that first surely regex can do what i want in 1 line.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with `preg_replace()`? This seems to work fine: https://3v4l.org/TBnOe (output is: `for(vari=0;i<aLinks.length;i++){`)

Comment: Do you output on CLI or in your browser? Did you take a look at the source of the page, most likely your browser interprets `<` as the start of an HTML element and doesn't display from that char on

Comment: omg how embarrassing!!! yes i'm viewing in the browser. Should i delete this or leave it here, possibly there are others as thick as me lol

Comment: It's a good question, perhaps you'd like to answer it yourself @FeelsUnique? You can edit your title as well and add "in the browser" to make it reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a stupid school boy error. I was viewing the output in a browser so it was interpreting the "<" as a tag and everything after that was invisible. Simply viewing the source in the browser showed it was actually working exactly as expected.